# How to check if the URL contains any number or empty?

Tags: javascript, php

Hi everyone please I need you're help !!

How could I do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       if (window.location.href.indexOf(" ") > -1) {
         alert("your url index is empty");
       }
    });
</script>
```

I need to know whene my Url index contain something (ID number) or empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get the job done:

```
   if (window.location.href.match(/\d+/g)) {
     alert("your url index is empty");
   }
```